# Regex with start and end strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have an example code

```
<h1>
    <asp:Literal ID="ltAccountTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</h1>
<p>
   <asp:Literal ID="ltNetBalance" runat="server" Text="Net balance" meta:resourcekey="ltNetBalanceResource"></asp:Literal>
   <span>
       <asp:Literal ID="ltNetBalanceAmount" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   </span>
</p>
```

I want to write a regular expression to find strings inside a long string.

Matches:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltAccountTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

and

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltNetBalanceAmount" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Actually I am using the code below to get all matches into string list. With which regular expression I can get it? I've tried many things for pattern variable but couldnt solve this problem.

```
 var lst = new List<string>();
 var mcol = Regex.Matches(text2, pattern);

 foreach (Match m in mcol)
 {
    lst.Add(m.Value);
 }
```

Comment: just suggestion: instead of regex check http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to capture. Can you provide an example?

Comment: +1 for `HtmlAgilityPack`; regexes are generally a poor choice for parsing HTML

Comment: are you just wanting `pattern = "<asp:Literal ID=\"[^\"]+\" runat=\"server\"></asp:Literal>"`

Comment: I used HTMLAgilityPack but it does not able to find aspx controls such as <asp:Button or label,literal etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get only literals that have ID and runat server tags, if yes the following works fine for me and gets exactly 2 literals

```
static void TestRegEx()
{
    string input = "<h1>"
        + "<asp:Literal ID=\"ltAccountTitle\" runat=\"server\"></asp:Literal>"
        + "</h1>"
        + "<p>"
        + "<asp:Literal ID=\"ltNetBalance\" runat=\"server\" Text=\"Net balance\" meta:resourcekey=\"ltNetBalanceResource\"></asp:Literal>"
        + "<span>"
        + "<asp:Literal ID=\"ltNetBalanceAmount\" runat=\"server\"></asp:Literal>"
        + "</span>"
        + " </p>";

    var collection = Regex.Matches(input, "<asp:Literal ID=\"\\w*\" runat=\"server\"></asp:Literal>");

    foreach (Match item in collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    }
```

}