# Find string with many names which are not know at the same time in a string

Tags: c#, regex

i have the following selfmade definition in on of our customer files:

```
<bitmaskdef name=SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_1>  

 ..content

</bitmaskdef>
```

I had to read out the content between the open and closing tags of the bitmask def.
To achive that, i've used regex in my c# code as following:

```
var bitmaskDefinitionRegex = new Regex(string.Format(@"<bitmaskdef name={0}>(.*?)</bitmaskdef>", bitmaskName));
```

bitmaskName contains the name of the bitmask we are searching for, for example: SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_1

Now our customer wants to change the definition as following:

```
<bitmaskdef name=SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_1; SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_2; SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_3; SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_4>

...content

</bitmaskdef>
```

So that he can set more than one name for the definition. With the current solution it is not able to get the content between the definition. Thats why i thought to change my RegEx but it currently don't know how. Important to know is, that i always only know one of the names.

For example:

- Reading out the name SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_1
- Find the definition for the name SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_1
- Reading out the name SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_2
- Find the definition for the name SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_2
- Reading out the name SDC_STATUS_BITMASKM_X
- and so on

So far my current solution is not working because i only consider one name, but now i need a solution to find the definition with the content also if there are many other names defined.

**Update #1**
Here is the way im looking for the regex match. The field "**fc**" is my file content of the "textfile" which contains the xml like definition.

```
var bitmaskDefinitionMatch = bitmaskDefinitionRegex.Match(String.Join(String.Empty, fc.ToArray()));
```

Comment: Your data almost looks like XML. Why not use XML and the built-in XML libraries rather than RegEx?

Comment: As you are proposing the problem (i.e., part of the required information is unknown) it seems that there is no possible solution by using Regex or any other thing. You should focus on what is for sure known (e.g., closing tags), and use this information to know the unknowns. Note that, a while ago, I wrote a Split-based solution for a problem equivalent to this one, which should also work with you (once you get properly, known input conditions): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010313/regex-with-start-and-end-strings/22010714#22010714

Comment: @Enigmativity : Yes it looks like XML but its not an XML file at all. Its a file with many other wired definitions which are not XML like.
@ varocarbas : I have to read in a text file, the start and closing tags are in different rows. I've made an update on my starting post. So far im getting the whole file content and looking for the close and ending tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
new Regex(string.Format(@"<bitmaskdef name=[^>]*?{0}(?:>|;[^>]*>)(.*?)</bitmaskdef>", bitmaskName));
```

It will match any `bitmaskdef` tag whose name attribute includes `bitmaskName`, demo here: http://regex101.com/r/lR0kG6